# How to bind to _.throttle on scroll event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, lodash, throttling

How do I throttle in React a function called on scroll that uses bind like the following?

```
this.getElementPosition = this.getElementPosition.bind(this);
```

What I have so far is the following, but it returns me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

```
throttle() {
  _.throttle((this.getElementPosition = this.getElementPosition.bind(this)), 100)
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.throttle)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.throttle);
}

getElementPosition() {
  var rect = this.elementPosition.getBoundingClientRect();

  if ((rect.top > 0) && (rect.top < (window.innerHeight * 0.75))) {
    this.elementPosition.setAttribute("data-position","in-viewport");
  } else if (rect.top > window.innerHeight) {
    this.elementPosition.setAttribute("data-position","below-viewport");
  } else if (rect.bottom < 0) {
    this.elementPosition.setAttribute("data-position","above-viewport");
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref={(element) => { this.elementPosition = element; }} data-position="below-viewport">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This means you don't have getElementPosition defined,  please post full code of component so we can see whats wrong, it just might be typo even.

Comment: @Geoman I've just added the rest of the code

Comment: I'm not familiar with thorttle but you should bind it in costructor as well if you want this inside thorttle to be same as this in class component.

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'

class Scroller extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.element = React.createRef()
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this)
    this.onScrollThrottled = throttle(this.onScroll, 300)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.element.current.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollThrottled)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.element.current.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollThrottled)
  }

  onScroll(e) {
    console.log(e.target.scrollTop)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.element}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Lodash `throttle` returns a function, so wrapping it with another function (method class) will force you to invoke it

```
onScrollThrottled() { return throttle(this.onScroll, 300) }
componentDidMount() {
  this.element.current.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollThrottled())
}
```

And `throttle(this.onScroll, 300)` **!==** `throttle(this.onScroll, 300)`, so you'll not be able to unsubscribe properly on `componentWillUnmount`. That's why I used class property instead. Also, I used standalone version of lodash throttle, which can be added via npm ([see doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle))

> npm i --save lodash.throttle

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, per lodash docs https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.doThrottle, 100))
}

doThrottle = () => {
  this.getElementPosition = this.getPosition()
}

getPosition = () => {
  // stuff
}
```

Note the arrow function on `doThrottle` and `getPosition` turns it into an implicit `bind(this)` in the component. The original problem was in your own throttle method in which `this` was not bound to your component.

Comment: I changed it as you suggest, but I'm still getting `TypeError: this.getElementPosition is not a function`

Comment: So the throttle/bind problem is solved? You should change one of the function names here: `this.getElementPosition = this.getElementPosition()`  thats probably not good. And check that you are using the `ref` properly. (updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind 'this' to thorttle as well in constructor.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.throttle = this.throttle.bind(this);
  this.getElementPosition = this.getElementPosition.bind(this)
}

throttle() {
 _.throttle(this.getElementPosition, 100)
}
```